# Chaining or chording very large job groups/tasks with Celery & Redis

Tags: python, parallel-processing, redis, celery, task-queue

I'm working on a project to parallelize some heavy simulation jobs. Each run takes about two minutes, takes 100% of the available CPU power, and generates over 100 MB of data. In order to execute the next step of the simulation, those results need to be combined into one huge result.

Note that this will be run on performant systems (currently testing on a machine with 16 GB ram and 12 cores, but will probably upgrade to bigger HW)

I can use a celery job group to easily dispatch about 10 of these jobs, and then chain that into the concatenation step and the next simulation. (Essentially a Celery chord) However, I need to be able to run at least 20 on this machine, and eventually 40 on a beefier machine. It seems that Redis doesn't allow for large enough objects on the result backend for me to do anything more than 13. I can't find any way to change this behavior.

I am currently doing the following, and it works fine:

```
test_a_group = celery.group(test_a(x) for x in ['foo', 'bar'])

test_a_result = rev_group.apply_async(add_to_parent=False)

return = test_b(test_a_result.get())
```

What I would rather do:

```
return chord(test_a_group, test_b())
```

The second one works for small datasets, but not large ones. It gives me a non-verbose 'Celery ChordError 104: connection refused' with large data.

**Test B returns very small data, essentially a pass fail, and I am only passing the group result into B, so it should work, except that I think the entire group is being appended to the result of B, in the form of parent, making it too big. I can't find out how to prevent this from happening.**

The first one works great, and I would be okay, except that it complains, saying:

> [2015-01-04 11:46:58,841: WARNING/Worker-6] /home/cmaclachlan/uriel-venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.py:45:
>
> RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!
> See http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks
>
> In Celery 3.2 this will result in an exception being
> raised instead of just being a warning.
>
> warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(E_WOULDBLOCK))

What the link essentially suggests is what I want to do, but can't.

I think I read somewhere that Redis has a limit of 500 mb on size of data pushed to it.

Any advice on this hairiest of problems?

Comment: In this situation my recommendation would be to save the results from the groups into files on some sort of centre wide filesystem.  Then using those files in `test_b()`

Comment: Thanks, but not so much of an option. No good network storage available to me, and I would definitely take an unnecessary performance hit writing gigabytes to disk and then immediately retrieving. And besides, the performance is clearly there, it's stupid that this functionality doesn't exist. Maybe I will try a different task queue.

Answer (score 0):

Celery isn't really designed to address this problem directly. Generally speaking, you want to keep the inputs/outputs of tasks small.

Every input or output has to be serialized (pickle by default) and transmitted through the broker, such as RabbitMQ or Redis. Since the broker needs to queue the messages when there are no clients available to handle them, you end up potentially paying the hit of writing/reading the data to disk anyway (at least for RabbitMQ).

Typically, people store large data outside of celery and just access it within the tasks by URI, ID, or something else unique. Common solutions are to use a shared network file system (as already mentioned), a database, memcached, or cloud storage like S3.

You definitely should not call .get() within a task because it can lead to deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, Pickle serialization is currently working fine, and it is very fast, certainly faster than writing gigabytes of data to disk. I guess that leads me to believe that RabbitMQ isn't a great option.

My temporary solution is to run the overall top-level 'job' synchronously from my web server, which is also clearly naughty in many ways. I'll need to manage long-running requests.

Comment: Another thought is to use the standard multiprocessing module, which also exchanges data using pickle without persistence: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html
I've seen it used successfully on projects where fault-tolerance isn't as important (no persistence or fail over) and installing a 3rd party broker wasn't an option.